# Connected graph such that any odd cycle is a cut set

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

In the country, some pairs of towns are connected by a two-way non-stop flight. From any town we can fly to any other (maybe not on only one flight). Given that if we consider any cyclic (i.e. beginning and finish towns match) route, consisting of an odd number of flights, and close all flights of this route, then we can find two towns such that we can't fly from one to the other.
Prove that we can divide the country into $4$ regions, such that any flight connects towns from different regions.
(Russian olympiad 2010)

Comment: The idea from original solution is following. We can take spanning tree and color it in colors 0 and 1. Also we can color the rest graph in colors 2 and 3.Then we can combine this two colorings.

Comment: @bigant146 Can you explain more?

Comment: What exactly do you want me to expalin?..